# ERC 721 not deployed as a contract

Tags: nft, erc-721, openzeppelin, hardhat

I am trying to deploy my ERC-721 contract on the Ropsten network. The deploy script successfully returns an address on which the contract is deployed. But, when I search for that address on the Etherscan, **it shows up as a normal address instead of a Contract**. What is it that I am doing wrong?
I am using OpenZepplin implementation, and Hardhat to deploy. Here is my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.3;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


contract Sakura is ERC721, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    string public proofFile = ""; // IPFS URL WILL BE ADDED LATER
    bool public saleIsActive = false;
    uint public reserve = 125;
    uint256 public cost = 0.05 ether;

    constructor() ERC721("Sakura", "SAKURA") {}

    function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI)
        public onlyOwner
        returns (uint256)
    {
        // require(msg.value >= cost, "Not enough ETH sent: check price.");

        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(recipient, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        return newItemId;
    }

    // function setTokenURIById (uint256 tokenId, string memory tokenURI) public onlyOwner{
    //     _setTokenURI(tokenId, tokenURI);
    // }
    

    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        uint balance = address(this).balance;
        msg.sender.transfer(balance);
    }

    function tokensOfOwner(address _owner) external view returns(uint256[] memory ) {
        uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
        if (tokenCount == 0) {
            // Return an empty array
            return new uint256[](0);
        } else {
            uint256[] memory result = new uint256[](tokenCount);
            uint256 index;
            for (index = 0; index < tokenCount; index++) {
                result[index] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, index);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    function setProvenanceHash(string memory provenanceHash) public onlyOwner {
        proofFile = provenanceHash;
    }

    function flipSaleState() public onlyOwner {
        saleIsActive = !saleIsActive;
    }
}
```

And this is the deploy script:

```
async function main() {
    // Grab the contract factory 
    const MyNFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("Sakura");
 
    // Start deployment, returning a promise that resolves to a contract object
    const myNFT = await MyNFT.deploy(); // Instance of the contract 
    console.log("Contract deployed to address:", myNFT.address);
 }
 
 main()
   .then(() => process.exit(0))
   .catch(error => {
     console.error(error);
     process.exit(1);
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function to create contract is called on a wallet address, which might take some time depending on network congestion, gas fees etc. If you keep refreshing the Etherscan page, you'll finally see the contract creation method called and the address changes from a normal address to a contract address.

[image: Contract creation image]